# Normal vector and time-function in the initial value formulation of General relativity

Tags: general-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, adm-formalism

I am trying to follow the initial-value and Hamiltonian formalism sections in Wald but I am confused about the definitions used to define hyper-surfaces. I am hoping that the conventions and variables used in Wald are fairly standard and that I do not need to provide the relevant section from the book. As far as I understand, we define a time function on our manifold and our hyper-surfaces are simply equipotential surfaces of the function. In addition, we also define a vector field given by $t^a$. However, what is the relation between the the vector field $t^a$ and the time function $t$? I thought it would be easy and convenient to define the vector field $t^a$ as the vector field normal to the hypersurfaces which means $t^a = g^{ab} \nabla_b t$. But this doesn't seem to be the case since we also have a normal vector to the hypersurfaces usually denoted by $n^a$. We then proceed to take the tangential and parallel components of $t^a$ to the hypersurfaces. This is really confusing to me.

What are the definitions of $t^a$, the time funtion $t$, and the normal vector $n^a$?